# Django + IIS Windows Server 2012 R2 error

Tags: python, django, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I am new into the server "world" and I have to make a django project work from a Windows Server 2012 R2.
I followed this tutorial: [Installing Django on IIS: A Step-by-Step Tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/django/installing-django-on-iis-a-step-by-step-tutorial).
I have a basic django project. When I start running my server it worked.

Before I removed my custom handler and leave the StaticFile handler as the most important one (according to the tutorial), I tested my site to see if it works:

->If I have added in the *FastCGI Settings* **Monitor changes to file** option, then I got **HTTP 500.0 Internal Server Error: File monitoring is enable for a file which could not be found - error code: 0x80070003.**
->If I removed the **Monitor changes to file** option then I got **HTTP Error 500.0- Internal Server Error C:\Python27\python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly error code - 0x00000002**.

After I followed the next step from tutorial and I added virtual directory for media and static, and I also removed the previous handler to leave the StaticFile handler as the most important one, I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YojgD.png) result, and when trying to access the admin page, got: **HTTP Error 404.4-Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable**.

And when I try to go back to using a custom handler as the most important one, even if I did all the changes back, it keeps using the StaticFile handler, even if I deleted the virtual directories too, and as a consequence I get the same result.

And when I try to run `python manage.py fcgi` command, it doesn't show anything it cmd, but creates a file in my project directory with the following content: `2016-10-20 12:01:24,013 [DEBUG] _recvall (8)` 
Can anyone help me? I searched on the internet solutions and examples to understand what is happening but none was helpful.